# Visual Studio Content Installer Error

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I am trying to build a Visual Studio extension and deploy the same in my Visual Studio 2010.
To demonstrate the creation of a Project site Template, I followed the following steps.

1. created Manually a Project website Template
2. created Files to be included in website Template
3. created a file with .vstemplate as extension in my project which has metadata information
4. created .vsi file for deployment of template for other users
5. The  .vsi file is installed sucessfully
6. But while creating a new website by selecting my template giving error
   could not find file

"C:\Documents and Settings..\Application Data\Microsoft\Visual Studio\10.0\
ProjectTemplatesCache\Visual C#\C Sharp\webproject.zip\webproject.webproj"

I am running VS 2010 on Wiondows XP-SP3. What is it that I am missing. Can anyone help?.
   Thanks InAdvance

Answer (score 0):

Make certain that the template zip file contains the webproject.webproj file. And that it is located in the zip file where you have indicated in the vstemplate entry that it would be.

The vstemplate file tells VS what files are needed, where to find them in the zip file, and where to put them in the newly created project. When it says a file is missing during project creation, it usually indicates that either the file is not present in the zip file, or that it is not located where its entry in the vstemplate file says it is.